# Error on POST data PHP

Tags: php, html, post

This is my scenario.

I have a form with a lot of input fields. A couple of them are input fields for urls... When I enter http://google.com (or any url), and I click the continue button, I get the following error

```
Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /new-product-action.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The name of the file which contains the form is `new-product.php` and the file receiving the post data is called `new-product-action.php`.

If I take out the url and enter just any character (not in this format http://blablabla.com), it will work.

For now, the `new-product-action.php` is just displaying the post data using

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Any thoughts into why when passing a string in url format, the system fails.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there html5 validation involved? How do you validate your input?

Comment: @Dorvalla yes, I am using type='url'

Comment: show us your form html source please?